# Impala: Select the data where only the row in table 2 with max(date) but less than a date in table 1 is returned

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, impala, row-number, correlated-subquery

I have a situation almost as same the example discussed in the below thread.

[select data where date is max(date) less than x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39469706/select-data-where-date-is-maxdate-less-than-x)

I have tables as

s_currency

```
cdate                          ratio                     currency                                            
-------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-06-06 00:00:00.0          1                         USD                                                 
2017-06-05 00:00:00.0          1                         USD                                                 
2017-06-04 00:00:00.0          1                         USD
```

s_transaction

```
tdate                          amount                    currency                                            
-------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-06-05 00:00:00.0          100                       USD                                                 
2017-06-08 00:00:00.0          55                        USD      
2017-06-08 00:00:00.0          55                        USD      
2017-06-08 00:00:00.0          60                        USD
```

And the result I want is

```
tdate                          amount    currency    ratio     cdate                                          
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-06-05 00:00:00.0          100        USD          1      2017-06-05 00:00:00.0                                
2017-06-08 00:00:00.0          55         USD          1      2017-06-06 00:00:00.0
2017-06-08 00:00:00.0          55         USD          1      2017-06-06 00:00:00.0    
2017-06-08 00:00:00.0          60         USD          1      2017-06-06 00:00:00.0
```

where the cdate should be based on the tdate, that its the latest currency date equal or earlier than the transaction date.

The solution in the other post uses a subquery in select clause, and it doesn't work in Impala. I tried using a CTE and joins with subqueries but none of them is returning the desired result. Below are some of the queries I built, and their results

```
 SELECT tdate, amount, t1.currency, ratio, cdate FROM s_transaction t1 , s_currency t2 
        WHERE t1.currency = t2.currency AND 
        t2.cdate = (select max(cdate) from s_currency 
                     where currency = t1.currency and cdate <= t1.tdate);
```

But this joins the tables and returns transactions for all the currencies less that the transaction date, so I get

```
   tdate                         amount       currency     ratio        cdate
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-06-08 00:00:00.0          60           USD          1            2017-06-05 00:00:00.0          
2017-06-08 00:00:00.0          60           USD          1            2017-06-06 00:00:00.0          
2017-06-08 00:00:00.0          60           USD          1            2017-06-04 00:00:00.0          
2017-06-05 00:00:00.0          100          USD          1            2017-06-05 00:00:00.0          
2017-06-05 00:00:00.0          100          USD          1            2017-06-04 00:00:00.0          
2017-06-08 00:00:00.0          55           USD          1            2017-06-05 00:00:00.0          
2017-06-08 00:00:00.0          55           USD          1            2017-06-06 00:00:00.0          
2017-06-08 00:00:00.0          55           USD          1            2017-06-04 00:00:00.0          
2017-06-08 00:00:00.0          55           USD          1            2017-06-05 00:00:00.0          
2017-06-08 00:00:00.0          55           USD          1            2017-06-06 00:00:00.0          
2017-06-08 00:00:00.0          55           USD          1            2017-06-04 00:00:00.0
```

So, i got rid of max(cdate) and used an order by with limit 1 but Impala throws an error that its **Unsupported correlated subquery with a LIMIT clause.**

I tried using CTE and wrote

```
with lastupdate as (
select t2.currency, ratio, max(cdate) as cdate from s_currency t2 join s_transaction t1
on cdate <= tdate and t2.currency = t1.currency group by t2.currency, ratio limit 1
) select t11.*, lst.ratio, lst.cdate
from s_transaction t11 join lastupdate lst
```

But here the CTE picks one value and uses it for all the transactions, so I get

```
tdate                         amount       currency     ratio        cdate
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-06-05 00:00:00.0          100          USD          1            2017-06-06 00:00:00.0          
2017-06-08 00:00:00.0          55           USD          1            2017-06-06 00:00:00.0          
2017-06-08 00:00:00.0          60           USD          1            2017-06-06 00:00:00.0          
2017-06-08 00:00:00.0          55           USD          1            2017-06-06 00:00:00.0
```

where the transaction on June 05, should have a cdate as June 05.

I even tried with a row_number() function in the subquery but it was not able to resolve the t1.tdate to compare the value of the date.

How can I achieve what I want ?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the following SQL statement in mysql db, it works.

```
select  tdate,amount,b.currency,ratio,max(cdate) from s_transaction a,s_currency b where a.tdate>=b.cdate group by tdate
```

Comment: I will have more than one transaction in the s_transaction table hence grouping by tdate will not help me... also I have more than the listed columns in my actual table, so using the aggregate function in the same select will make it very huge. Also the group by clause in your query has only tdate, I think it should have all the columns in the select except for max(cdate) listed in the group by clause

Comment: Is there any primary key in s_transaction table?
I guess you should have something like "transaction id" field in s_transaction table, if so you can group by "transaction id" and then get the maximum cdate and then finish.

Comment: I don't have a unique key, its basically a view so it will only have the columns that the view is supposed to have. I tried creating a row_number() and use it as a primary key, but it doesn't look great. I also doubt if its a defect in Impala... If I get a solution with row_number() that works, I will post that here

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar problem hence posting it here for reference.

#### TL,DR:We need to use the Impala's windowing function to filter the subquery results. Below is the SQL:

```
SELECT t.* FROM 
(
   SELECT rank() OVER (ORDER BY cdate DESC) daterank, c1.cdate, t1.*
   FROM s_currency c1, s_transaction t1
   WHERE c1.currency = t1.currency 
   AND c1.cdate <= t1.tdate
) t
WHERE t.daterank = 1;
```

#### Details:

The problem is Impala does not support complex operations in coorelated subqueries.

From the official Impala site : https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_limit.html & https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_subqueries.html

- Restrictions

  1. Correlated subqueries used in EXISTS and IN operators cannot include a LIMIT clause
  2. For the EXISTS and NOT EXISTS clauses, any subquery comparing values from the outer query block to another table must use at least one equality comparison, not exclusively other kinds of comparisons such as less than, greater than, BETWEEN, or !=.
- So what's a Correlated subquery?

  *Correlated subqueries compare one or more values from the outer query block to values referenced in the WHERE clause of the subquery. Each row evaluated by the outer WHERE clause can be evaluated using a different set of values. These kinds of subqueries are restricted in the kinds of comparisons they can do between columns of the inner and outer tables*
- I found the Impala's windowing function useful in this case especially rank to get over  max equivalent from subquery using limit (restriction 1) or less than (restriction 2)

  https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_analytic_functions.html

Answer (score 0):

You can uses a CTE with Lead to create a range that each currency ratio is valid for, and then join on that without using subqueries in the join. I found this to perform much faster than using rank.

```
WITH startend as (
    SELECT
        currency,
        ratio,
        cdate as starttime,
        ISNULL( LEAD(cdate) OVER ( PARTITION BY currency ORDER BY cdate), '9999-12-31') endtime
    FROM s_currency)
SELECT
    tdate,
    amount,
    t.currency,
    ratio,
    c.starttime as cdate
FROM s_transaction t
INNER JOIN startend c
    ON t.currency = c.currency
    AND tdate >= starttime
    AND tdate < endtime
```

Don't forget to add all of your join conditions to the partition clause.